# Magento 2 Test braintree card details

Tags: payment, magento2.3.5, braintree

I need to trigger transaction decline or any other failed payments in my sandbox but I'm enable to do so.
I've used this details ref:https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/ruby#test-value-4000111111111115

more specifically : `4000111111111115`

But still process the payment and no error transaction declined message.

Any suggestion please!

Answer (score 0):

The option i've found is to create a product with price £5,001.00

which is specified here:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/ruby#amount-500100

Thanks